# My collision object eats my cloth simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation, collision

Some of my collision objects are literally eating up my cloth simulation and yet some of them aren't. Any idea on why this is happening? Thanks in advance.[image][image]

Comment: did you bake?..

Comment: Apply all scales and check your normals.

Comment: Baking it seemed to have no effect, but applying scales and overlooking my normals helped only to a certain degree as the issue still persists the pipe itself is no longer doing it but curved objects seemed to have this effect where they let the cloth trough and then hold the cloth behind them